# Say that $(x_n)\rightarrow x$ in a metric space $X$. Can we say that for any $n$, $d(x_n,x_{n+1})+d(x_{n+1},x_{n+2})+\dots\ge d(x_n,x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say that $(x_n)\rightarrow x$ in a metric space $X$.  Can we say that for any $n$, $d(x_n,x_{n+1})+d(x_{n+1},x_{n+2})+\dots \geq d(x_n,x)$?

I see it as an infinite triangle inequality.

EDIT: I had $\leq$ instead of $\geq$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the correct direction of the inequality, yes, we have

$$d(x_n,x) \leqslant \sum_{k=0}^\infty d(x_{n+k},x_{n+k+1})$$

when $x_n \to x$. We have:

$$d(x_n,x) \leftarrow d(x_n,x_{n+k}) \leqslant \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} d(x_{n+m},x_{n+m+1}) \leqslant \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} d(x_{n+m},x_{n+m+1})$$

Of course, the right hand side will often be infinite, then there is little information in the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

You have the triangle inequality pointing the wrong way.